MongoDB: Check if a value is true or false in a collection
I am making a FFlag system for my game, I am using MongoDB for it. I wanna check if a certain value in this collection is true or false. Here is my code:


if FFlagsData:FindOne({["allowRebirthing"] = true }) then
    print("Test1")
else if FFlagsData:FindOne({["allowRebirthing"] = false }) then
        print("Test2")
    end
end



image of my collection

In Lua, the colon : is typically used for method calls, not for specifying object properties directly. Instead, you should use the equality operator = to specify the property and its value in a Lua table.
So, in Lua, your query object should be written like this:
{ allowRebirthing = true }
Plus, removed the square brackets around the field names. MongoDB queries do not need square brackets around field names.
({ allowRebirthing = true })
({ allowRebirthing = false })

Hi, I am using a custom module made by another developer called "Rongo", since Roblox Lua doesn't support MongoDB natively. This does not work for me, I think it has something to do with my module.

it's possible that the syntax differs. In that case, you may need to consult the documentation from Rongo.

Forgot to mention, the code does work, it only returns "true" though. Might help you solve this.
